# Can't make walking animations in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I was trying to code a game in pygame, but then when I tried to make a walking animation it only displayed one of the sprites.

```
def go_left(time):
    ness_current = 1
    global ness
    global is_walking_left
    ness_list = [ness_walking,ness_standing]
    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    go_left.walking_steps = 1
    now = 0
    cooldown = 1000
    flag = 0
    ness = ness_list[ness_current]
    print current_time - game_loop.animation_timer
    if (current_time - game_loop.animation_timer) > 200:
        print 'Changing'
        if ness_current == 0:
            print 'Changing to sprite 1'
            now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
            ness_current = 1
            current_time = now
        elif ness_current == 1:
            print 'Changing to sprite 0'
            if (current_time - game_loop.animation_timer) > 200:
                ness_current = 0
                current_time = now


        else:
            'Changing to sprite 0 because of sprite reset'
            ness_current = 0

    current_time = now

def stop_it():
    global ness
    ness = pygame.image.load('nessthekid.png').convert()
    ness.set_colorkey(WHITE)

car_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
player_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
```

When I try to use this it only displays one of the sprites not the other for the character. I want it to swich every 1 or 2 seconds to make it look like its walking. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First, I highly suggest using a class, to avoid using global variables.

Second, as you set the current time back to now (0), you will make it so current_time - game_loop.animation_timer will always be negative.  This will keep the statement from running.

For now, I suggest completely removing the "if (current_time - game_loop.animation_timer) > 200:" from your code.

Here is an example to get you started (obviously you will have to alter it to make it work for you)

```
class Ness:
    def __init__(self):
        self.all_images = [ness_walking,ness_standing]
        self.current = 0
        self.image = self.all_images[self.current]

    def walk_left(self):
        # Every 200 clicks
        if pygame.time.get_ticks() % 200 == 0:
            if self.current == 0:
                self.current = 1
            else:
                self.current = 0
        self.image = self.all_images[self.current]
```

Comment: Ok now its not changing the sprite at all when I removed it

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Red Twoon put the stuff separated in class is a very good practice. Another thing that you should do is no rely in get_ticks directly but instead use some kind of time independent movement/animation.
You can achieve this using delta times in your game loop.

## Game loop.

```
while(True):
    delta = #Get the delta time.
    handle_events();
    update(delta);
    draw(delta);

#Animation stuff.
time_to_animate_frame = 200;
time_since_last_update = 0;
...

time_since_last_update += delta;
if(time_since_last_update > time_to_animate_frame):
    time_since_last_update - time_to_animate_frame;
    #Do the animation.....
```